# Error in if (getOption("Cardinal.dark")) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, shiny

I tried to run the following code based on the example code provided by [LinkToCode](https://github.com/kuwisdelu/CardinalVis)
, but it gives the this error message `Error in if (getOption("Cardinal.dark")) { : argument is of length zero` .

**Code in R**:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    CardinalVis::msiVis(pig206)  
    # data(pig206, package="CardinalWorkflows")
    # pig206 <- as(pig206, "MSImagingExperiment")
    # CardinalVis::msiVis(pig206) }) # this is reactive
  
)


server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  
  data(pig206, package="CardinalWorkflows")
  pig206 <- as(pig206, "MSImagingExperiment")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Reach out to that GH repository owner? It seems to be related to an error in a function they created.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem, and I would like to briefly address it below:
1- The package requires R(version "4.1").
2- Updates of the fansi (version "0.5") and signal (version "0.7-6") are required
3- the Cardinal.dark option is a bug that was addressed in this [link](https://github.com/kuwisdelu/Cardinal/blob/master/NEWS)

to get around this issue, and fix it from within Rstudi, simply try:
options(Cardinal.dark = FALSE)

then the package works fine:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Huqg.png)